# Unable to debug in Eclipse (Arm toolchain): Internal error occurred during "launching name"

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am having a problem debugging in linux eclipse. When I run the debugger, I get the following error:

> An internal error occurred during: "Launching (program name)".
>   org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.service.GdbDebugServicesFactory.(Ljava/lang/String;)V

For more info, I am trying to debug a simple hello world tutorial using GDB QEMU. After I close out the error it appears to have started a debug session, which I am then unable to terminate.

Anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: You have tagged this as Java, but isn't the ARM toolchain C/C++ for Arduino?

Comment: Sorry, I tagged Java because it appears to be a java error. I am using eclipse, which in turn uses java and I think that is where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I am having the same problem after updating some eclipse modules, except the offender is "GdbDebugServicesFactory.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;)V".  Any body have any ideas?

Comment: I think this was a bug with eclipse neon not being compatible with the build tools (Although I thought I saw that the most recent version was). I switched to Mars and it worked fine.